# Find $\tan C$ in a triangle satisfying the constraint

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

Given a triangle with angles $A,B, C$ and sides $a, b, c$ opposite to their respective angles, how can I find $\tan C$ such that

$$c^2={a^3+b^3+c^3\over a+b+c}$$

I used the law of Cosines on the LHS as well as on the cube terms but I don't know exactly I'm looking for in manipulating the expression. Should I try to get $\sin C$ and $\cos C$ separately, or is there a more elegant way of doing things? I believe there is since this is an old competition problem, I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we know that $c^2(a+b+c)=(a^3+b^3+c^3)$, that is equivalent to $ a c^2 + b c^2 = a^3 + b^3 $ or to $c^2 = a^2+b^2-ab $, we know that $\cos C=\frac{1}{2}$ due to the Cosine theorem.

That gives $\color{red}{\tan C=\sqrt{3}}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$c^2={a^3+b^3+c^3\over a+b+c} \Rightarrow  c^2(a+b+c)=(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$

So $$c^2a+c^2b+c^3=a^3+b^3+c^3$$

$$\Rightarrow c^2a+c^2b=a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Since $a,b$ are non zero , $a+b \neq0$.

Thus $$c^2=(a^2-ab+b^2) \Rightarrow ab = a^2+b^2-c^2$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$

Thus $$\cos C = \frac{1}{2} $$